# Error de conexión con RDS PostgreSQL AWS Django

Tags: django, postgresql, aws

Intento desplegar una aplicación django en AWS haciendo uso de S3 y RDS, pero cuando intento conectar con la base de datos PostgreSQL de AWS me arroja el siguiente error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "sifos.xxxxx.sa-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (172.x.x.x) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

¿Debo dejarla accesible?

```
Publicly accessible
No
```

Actualmente tengo esta configuración en las reglas de entrada.

[image: Configuración reglas entrada AWS]

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso la solución fue dejarla accesible, es decir cambiar desde la consola de AWS el atributo:

```
Publicly accessible
Yes
```